# Kendo UI, how do you remove space before and after a bar chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I am trying to remove the space before and after the Kendo UI chart below with no luck. Is this a gap and spacing issue?  My goal is to have a single line bar chart with the grey only appearing on the right.

[JSFiddle Codes Here](http://jsfiddle.net/esoteric/3VXqA/)

```
$(document).ready(allFamilyTicketsBarChartThisYear);

function allFamilyTicketsBarChartThisYear() {
    $("#chart-7").kendoChart({
        title: {
            visible: false,
        },
        legend: {
            visible: false,
        },
        chartArea: {
            height: 90,
            padding: 0,
            margin: 0,
            background: "transparent"
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: "bar",
        },
        series: [
            {
                //gap: 0,
                //spacing: 0,
                //border: {
                //    width: 0
                //},
                // the above removes the height of the bar
                name: "monthThisYear",
                data: [506785]
            }
        ],
        valueAxis: {
            max: 1000000,
            labels: {
                visible: false
            },
            line: {
                visible: false
            },
            minorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            },
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        categoryAxis: {
            line: {
                visible: false
            },
            minorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            },
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            visible: false,
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hide the category axis instead of the grid lines, it looks like what I think you are describing (http://jsfiddle.net/3VXqA/2/)

```
 categoryAxis: {
         visible: false
 },
```